# Unable to read in /root directory even though sudo

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, root

I have a bash script with something like

```
while read -r name value
do
    ....something
done < "test"
```

I'm running this script as normal user.

Now I wanted to store this file in the `/root` home directory and read it from there.
Doing

```
while read -r name value
do
    ....something
done < "/root/path/to/file"
```

of course I get the error: `./script: ine xy: /root/path/to/file: Permission Denied`

Than I tried

```
while sudo read -r name value
do
    ....something
done < "/root/path/to/file"
```

But this gives me: `sudo: read: unknown command`

Why can't I read a file in the `/root` home-directory though I use `sudo`?

**EDIT**
I tried a bit further and found out that I cannot even do

```
$> sudo echo "test" /root/.test
[sudo] Password for user:
-bash: /root/.test: Permission Denied
```

**EDIT 2**
It works as I want if I run the complete script with `sudo ./myscript` but I prefer not doing that ... Is there another way?

Comment: *"Why can't I read a file in the /root home-directory though I use sudo?"* because `read` is a shell builtin - `sudo` only works with external commands

Comment: ok so how could I do it than since I don't want to run the whole script as sudo ...?

Comment: I think running the script as root is the best option **if** you need to read files in `/root` - but why do you want to do that?

Comment: What is the permissions of `/root`  and your file within the `/root` ?

Comment: Because I want normal users be able to use the script. But if I login as root (sudo -i) it would be nice if I have the file directly in the homedirectoy and not having to serach for it first

Comment: Then you should put it in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: `drwx------  23 root root  4096 Jun 21 13:09 root/`  
`-rw-r--r--  1 root root     5 Jun 21 13:40 .test`

Comment: @Ravexina does it change anything if I have it in `/bin/myscript` or `/usr/local/bin/myscript` ?

Comment: In `/bin` it might be overwritten with a program when you are installing it using `apt-get`, also it's against the FHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why does it not work?

The reason your approach does not work is that you are reading the file using `<` "stdin", it means your shell is in charge of reading the file and you ran it using a regular user so it does not have the necessary rights to read the file. Now you should know that running the `read` command using `sudo` will not going to help not to mention that it's a shell built-in which can not be run using `sudo`, like `cd` etc.

#### How do I get it to work?

The only thing you should do is somehow reading the file vi `root` or a user/group with necessary privilege. So You can do it like:

```
sudo cat /root/txt | while read -r name value;
do
  some command
done
```

in this case only `cat` will be run with `sudo`.

However the best practice is to put your script in `/usr/local/bin` so everybody has access to run it.

Also note that when you want to redirect something to `/root/example` you should use `sudo tee`:

```
echo test | sudo tee file
```

or run the whole script using `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

/root folder is for root only. I believe only the system can manipulate files there. you can try with `su' but I think you will get the same result.

secondly: it is not recommended to run normal programs with root privileges.

when you use sudo in the command line you supply the password and become root. the script can not do this. it is a security measure to insure that someone at the terminal is making the changes. also some actions and folders are available to the root  system process only.

Comment: to the first: as said it runs totaly fine if I do sudo ./myscript or if I try directly using sudo -i.  
To the second: I know! That's why I don't want to use sudo ./myscript but rather would prefere some code that works

Comment: then put the program in your home folder. then you won't need sudo to run it. you voted my answer down??  I answered your question "Why can't a run a program in /root even though I use sudo?"

Comment: no, I have the script in /bin/blabla since I want it to runable by every user. And it does not matter wether it lies in my folder or the bin/blabla result is the same. Finally: "Why can't a run a program in /root even though I use sudo?" is not my question but "Why can't I read a file in the /root home-directory though I use sudo?"

Comment: well same answer, /root is system root only the script does not have root privileges

Comment: than why can't I do `sudo echo "test" > /root/.test` ? I am running it with sudo so I should have root privileges

Comment: but sudo group is not root

Comment: Now I get what you mean. Sorry then, if you edit your answer I can vote it up but as it is it was absolutely not clear for me. Anyway why can one do e.g. `sudo nano /root/.test` .. since I'm still not root but only sudo this also should not work ... I have my script working now but still confused..

Comment: edited the post